# ExoPlayer : Uri : Not able to load local media Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to play media from mobile phone into ExoPlayer.
I am getting the path from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();`

Whenever I try to play media- I got this error-

> Source error
>    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException:
>   Unable to connect to /storage/emulated/0/Download/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

also,

> Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /storage/emulated/0/Download/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

I am passing Uri here `MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(link));`

This method is using the Uri

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new 
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua", BANDWIDTH_METER);
    DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory = new 
DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
    return new DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, 
dashChunkSourceFactory, null, null);
}
```

This is how i am getting the link

```
arrayList1 = video(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile());
protected ArrayList<File> video(File file) {
    File[] filename = file.listFiles();
    ArrayList<File>  arrayList2 = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        for (File file1 : filename) {
            if (file1.isDirectory()) {
                arrayList2.addAll(video(file1));
            } else {
                if (file1.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    arrayList2.add(file1);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return arrayList2;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are creating the `Uri` and giving it to ExoPlayer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the post

Comment: Stop using `Uri.parse()`. Use `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare after using this- Uri.fromFile(new File(link));

My error is : 
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection

-also-

Unexpected exception loading stream
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection

Comment: Perhaps stop using `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory`, since that would appear to be tied to HTTP, and your data source is not using HTTP.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You very much! Problem is solved

Answer (score 6):

Use a [FileDataSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/FileDataSourceFactory.java). The following snippet creates a MediaSource for mp4 from an asset uri like file:///android_asset/video.mp4 or other file uris:

```
  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new FileDataSourceFactory();
    return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, 
        new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case .mp4 file not support so, first i had tried to put local **.mp4** file then check but exoplayer not support. I have call **.m3u8** url and it work very fine.

```
https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8
```